# OpenShift NextGen and Rails - An unhandled lowlevel error occurred

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift, production

I'm an OpenShift newbie and just a while ago I managed to deploy a basic Rails app with the Next Gen console.
I did a few tweaks to the app, namely created a home controller with

```
`rails g controller home index`
```

and updated the `config/routes.rb` file by setting the root route to `root 'home#index'` instead of `get 'home/index'`.
Now the local rails server points correctly to the index page when running in development environment, so there is no problem at all.
But when I pushed the updated content to the git remote repository and and started a new build with

```
oc start-build <app>
```

and reloaded the page with the OpenShift production environment, nothing is shown but

```
An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.
```

Edit: the command `oc logs dc/<app>` returned me this as "root error":

```
#<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
```

Then my `config/secrets.yml` in the production section reads:

```
# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Now I guess this has to do with setting up environment variables in an OpenShift environment. I found out the command

```
oc env dc/<app> <ENV_VARIABLE>=<value>
```

from [this guide](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/environment_variables.html#set-environment-variables). Is it the correct one? If yes, how to generate a proper SECRET_KEY_BASE value?

Any help is of course highly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Did you try actually looking at the logs? https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/log-files.html

Comment: I stumbled across the command `oc logs dc/<app>` and will write its response on my question, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I found out eventually the `rake secret` command generates a hash for you, then used `oc env dc/<app> SECRET_KEY_BASE=<hash>` and rebuilt the app with `oc start-build <app>`